# How can I structure the HTML for these requirements

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I am developing a system where I will display content in a browser in an embedded application. The normal browser navigation controls cannot be used but instead will have javascript running in a wrapper round the page. The content will be coming from the same domain but I cannot pre-process the content. Needs to be compliant with IE8+ and latest of FF and chrome.

The things the javascript needs to do are..

- Load in new content
- Detect when the content has fully loaded
- Set focus to elements
- Detect which link currently has focus
- Retrieve lists of links on the page
- Trigger links

What is the best way to place the content html pages within the wrapper page? eg

- frames
- iframe
- div

Comment: Frames are deprecated since forever. In general, if you can avoid it, don't use iframes. But I'm guessing you are not allowed to mess with the loaded content in any way, so isolating it in an iframe would be best. After that you can mess with it in any way you like. Looking at the requirements I'm inclined to think jQuery will be sufficient. `$('a.someclass').focus()` to set focus, `$('a.someclass:focus')` to get focused elements and `$('a)` to get all links. If you read the documentation you'll find out that $(...) accepts a second parameter: context. Pass in a reference to your iframe.

Comment: The question is too abstract, and if clarified, would probably become primarily an opinion issue (choice of design approaches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both iframes and divs could work. The final choice will depend on the details of your implementation, and is also a matter of personal taste.

With divs, the html becomes part of your wrapper page. The risk is to have conflicts between the inserted content and the rest of the page (css, html ids for example).

An iframe creates a sandbox and avoids conflicts. The downside is that the layout is not easy to adjust as the content lives in its own document. html5 introduces new iframe attributes like "seamless", but they won't work in IE8.

Comment: Thanks for getting in a reply before the stackoverflow police close the question down.

Answer (score 0):

As above, Iframes may be best; however they are deprecated and don't always give the best results. An alternative would be to set a div for the content, and Ajax the content into the frame. You can then access it through the dom to get links etc.

To decide which would be best I would consider what content is being loaded - full HTML documents (with doctype, head, metadata etc) will be problematic without I frames.
If the content being loaded is just plain text, maybe with a few basic HTML elements, I would ajax it into a div

Comment: So their not, my mistake. In that case this would certainly be a good case for iframes, although I would recomend you integrate it with the containing document as best as possible; I notice their is a new Seamless attribute for this very reason